# Using paste in left_join in R

Tags: r, left-join, paste

I have a couple of dataframes like car.a and car.b, .... I want to use `paste` to `left_join` these dataframes to another dataset, but the following code does not work:

```
mode <-  "a"
left_join(df,paste("car.",mode,sep=""), by=c("year")) 

Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `get` to retun the value of the object

```
left_join(df, get(paste("car.",mode,sep="")), by=c("year"))
```